# ServiceStack update to 6.10.0

Tags: .net-6.0, servicestack

in my project i've installed ServiceStack v. 6.9.0. Now I'm trying to update to v.6.10.0, but i'm getting the following error
**Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes**
My project is .NET 6.

I'ave also tried to update to .NET 7 but nothing changes.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All [ServiceStack Project Templates](https://servicestack.net/start) use wildcard for their [.csproj dependencies](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/web/blob/master/MyApp/MyApp.csproj), e.g:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="ServiceStack" Version="6.*" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

If you change it to wildcards then do a **dotnet restore** it will install the latest version on NuGet which is **v6.10.0**. If you have a dependency that's blocking the install of the latest version it should show up in the error messages.

Comment: thanks @mythz. But why is it happened? i've also downloaded the nuget package as i've always done..

Comment: @paoloterruccio no idea, you've not provided the full error logs to have any chance in being able to identify the issue